# Nodejs - throw unpredictable error as `property 'get' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run my `node` app. But I am getting an error, which I am not able to understand. please any one help me to understand this?

here is my code :

```
var express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  path = require("path");

app.get("/", function( req, res ) {
    res.sendfile( path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

var adminRouter = express.Router();

adminRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('I am the dashboard!');
});

app.use("/admin", adminRouter);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
console.log("basic app listeners!");
```

the error I am getting is :

```
adminRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:16:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:990:3
```

Can any one help me? I am running my app in `cloud9`.

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try: `express.Router().route()` . It is not depreciated.

Comment: Your code looks correct and I cannot reproduce the problem. What version of node and express are you using?

Comment: did you created run configuration for express  in `cloud9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your express version less than +4 , probably version 3. Try

```
npm uninstall express --save
```

Then re-install.

```
adminRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.send('I am the dashboard!');
});
```

try it like this as well.

```
 adminRouter.route('/').get(function(req,res){
res.json({'hello there from main route!'});
});
```

Comment: best bet is to delete your node_modules folder. Change the express version to latest and re run npm install on the updated json package. cloud 9 does not support express version +4.x. That's the main reason for not executing the code correctly.

Comment: 4.15.2 is the latest for express.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is express version problem.

`express.Router();` is supported on version **4.x** and **cloud 9** support by default **3.x**

change your package.json

**"express": "^4.15.2",**

and delete node_module folder
then run

`npm install`